# Writing columns to a CSV file c#

Tags: c#, wpf

is there a way to export data to a specific column in a CSV file? I have data exporting to appending rows but need to specify which columns to save to.

my saving code is:

```
{
StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("log.csv");                
            {

                    //need this in column 1
                    sw.WriteLine(TextBox21.Text + ",");
                    //need this in column 2
                    sw.WriteLine(TextBox41.Text + ",");

            }

            sw.Close();
```

Comment: I'm confused.  By definition the columns in your CSV file are determined by the positions of the comma's.  How is your above code failing?

Comment: @rie819 I didn't spot it at first either, but he's using WriteLine() instead of Write(), so each field is it's own row.

Answer (score 4):

yes, like so:

```
var columns = new string[10];

columns[5] = "hello";

sw.WriteLine( string.Join( ",", columns ));
```

Comment: Please be aware this handles only the simplest cases (no commas, quotes, or newlines in data, encoding unspecified, ...) Such oversimplified "solutions" tend to break soon after being released into the real world.

Answer (score 3):

Creating CSV output is a solved problem and you should not have to create your own writer. Naive "solutions" like appending commas will break as soon as you start getting data with commas, quotes, newlines, other encodings, and such.

There are many working, debugged, documented, high-performance CSV writer ready for you to use, such as [FastCSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader), [CSVHelper](http://csvhelper.com/), LINQ to CSV and others. I have used FastCSV and found it simple to use, reliable, and performant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your question as "how do I update/add a column in an already existing csv file".

You can use the oledb driver for text:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27802/Using-OleDb-to-Import-Text-Files-tab-CSV-custom

You may have to read the file in as a datatable, update the datatable's column and then re-export it as csv if the oledb driver doesn't support update (It might, I'm sometimes surprised by how much is supported by text drivers)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're calling `WriteLine` twice, which results in each value appearing as a row in the table. The least amount of code change to make it put them both in the same row is to change the first `WriteLine` to a `Write`. And, there's no need to include the trailing comma.

```
StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("log.csv");                
{
    sw.Write(TextBox21.Text + ",");  // Column 1
    sw.WriteLine(TextBox41.Text);    // Column 2
}
sw.Close();
```

If you need to leave certain columns blank (to skip ahead to a later column) then just output additional commas without values.

Comment: thanks for the help, how would i code if i wanted to add more columns than 2? i have 40 text boxes in total

Answer (score 1):

Just change your first `.WriteLine()` to `.Write()`.

And while you're at it, you probably want to encase those text fields in quotes. If someone puts a comma in one of those fields it will throw your log reader off later on.